# How to autoSizeTextType to unifrom programatically?

Tags: android, textview

It's possible to do this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

But property `autoSizeTextType` is able only for `API LEVEL >= 26`, and Android Studio shows annoying warning about that.

In order to get rid of that, I want to do that programmatically, but there are 3 methods:

```
textView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes(...)
textView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(...)
```

These two require configuration, but I want to be a default configuration, the same as `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`.

```
textView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(TextView.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
```

This says:

```
AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support).
```

PS: I wrap up the code into:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT= > 26) {...}
```

Comment: TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.text_view); 


TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (textview, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `TextViewCompat` class for avoid the Library Restriction error. Like,

```
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textView,TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
```